# Problem with Intersect_Analysis : too long path?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I made a python code for Arcgis 9.3. to intersect 2 features.

The problem is that code works when the files are on my desktop (for example)
but not when they are in a long path on another disc.

Here is the example with a long path :

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting, glob

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()


ShapeVitesse ="X:/D1111134_PPRI_ARQUES/01_Technique/1.1_Hydrologie/111_Données-de-pluies/1114_Données Radar/TEST/Hauteurs.shp"
ShapeHauteur ="X:/D1111134_PPRI_ARQUES/01_Technique/1.1_Hydrologie/111_Données-de-pluies/1114_Données Radar/TEST/Vitesses.shp"
FichierSortie ="X:/D1111134_PPRI_ARQUES/01_Technique/1.1_Hydrologie/111_Données-de-pluies/1114_Données Radar/TEST/ALEA.shp"


Input_Features = ShapeVitesse +" #;"+ShapeHauteur
# Process: Intersect...
gp.Intersect_analysis(Input_Features, FichierSortie, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
```

Is there a solution or is it impossible to make it with too long path ?

But the tool intersect in ArctoolBox works with these path ???!!!

Comment: Are you sure you deal with diacritic symbols fine in the code? You have those é in the path. Try moving the shape into a long path folder with only Latin characters. PS. I personally never use any other symbols than A-Z/0-9/_ in the file system object names. Never know how those will be treated by various software.

Comment: I tred to replace the é by e but even with this : it doesn't work

Comment: you also have spaces and dots

Comment: You are right ! It came from the space (end maybe also the é and the .) Sorry it was simple ^^

Comment: @radouxju, please wrap an answer we will vote on :)

Comment: You could have also turned the strings into unicodes using `.decode` (for example, `FichierS = "X:/111_Données-de-pluies/1114_Données Radar/ALEA.shp".decode("cp1252")`) so the string could be handled unambiguously by the software as unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the string should not be a problem in your case. For Python the maximum string length is more than 2 Go in 32-bit (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739913/what-is-the-max-length-of-a-python-string)). As mentioned in the comment, each individual path in the concatenated string is limited in the Windows API (with some exceptions like the use of "\?\" for very long paths). The maximum length for a path is defined MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. In other words, the constraint on the path length will usually come from Windows.

On the other hand, many softwares do not handle "special characters" properly (and arcpy is amongst them). In your case, there are **spaces** and **é** in the string, as well as a **dot** in the middle of your path. Try using only A-Z/0-9/_ in your paths folder to avoid this kind of issue.

EDIT  (credit to Jason Screirer's comment) :

If you can't change your path, you can turn the strings into unicodes using .decode (for example, FichierS = "X:/111_Données-de-pluies/1114_Données Radar/ALEA.shp".decode("cp1252")) so the string could be handled unambiguously by the software as unicode

Comment: Python string length limits do not apply to path name limits. There is [a constant defined as `MAX_PATH` on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) that is the absolute limit to the length of a path on disk.